# Internet Explorer and the Mouseenter function

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am self-teaching JQuery and have run into a bit of a snag.  What I've done is layered a div over the image, set visability to hidden, and use JQuery to state that when I mouseenter the image, the box is visable, and when I mouseleave, the box disappears. This works fine and dandy with Firefox, but in IE, when I mouse over, only the words appear and they don't disappear when the mouse leaves the div.

I know this question has been asked in many various forms, but so far my research has not provided a viable answer. I would greatly appreciate some advice.

My HTML:

```
<table>
<td class=presentation>
<a href="Capabilities-PDF.html" target="_blank"> <div class="cover hidden1"> Learn About Us </div> </a>
<div class="image1"><img
  title="Capabilities"
  alt="Capabilities"
  src="images/thumbnails/Capabilities.png"
class="img"></div></td>
</table>
</body>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.image1').mouseover(function(){
    $('.hidden1').show();
    });
$('.hidden1').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

My CSS:

```
.cover{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
height: 131px;
position: absolute;
width: 175px;
z-index: 1;
text-align: center;
color: ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;

}

.hidden1 {
display: none;
}
.image1 {
height: 131px;
width: 175px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Working for me with Chrome and IE9 : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/17/

Comment: have you tried mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout?

Comment: Yes I have, same result